# Cairo: Cropping a PDF Surface?

Tags: c++, pdf, cairo

Let's say I make a surface like this:

```
cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_pdf_surface_create("pdffile.pdf", 40000, 40000);
cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(surface);
```

That's a big surface! The reason for doing so is that I don't know the size of my drawing until I've plotted it (it's a complicated graph, generated on the fly). After I've plotted it, it seems pretty trivial to crop the surface. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw to a recording surface instead of a PDF surface. The recording surfaces can then be painted to a smaller PDF surface. Also, cairo supports unbounded recording surfaces, so this would even work when your drawing is wider/higher than 40k pixel.